# KeyError when appending to a Python dictionary with a string index

Tags: python, python-2.7, dictionary

I am getting the following error:

> KeyError: 'sat'

in my Python script as below:

```
balls = {}
balls_count = 0

for entry_content in latest_results_soup.find_all('img',vspace='12'):

    if balls_count < 5:
        draw_day = 'sat'
    else:
        draw_day = 'wed'

    balls[draw_day].append(int(entry_content['src'].rsplit('/', 1)[-1].split('.')[0]))

    balls_count += 1
```

What i'm looking for is either a dict or list to parse further down which has a structure something like:

```
balls['sat'] = [5, 7, 20, 28, 30]
balls['wed'] = [1, 6, 9, 19, 20]
```

I feel like I am close (Python n00b, BTW) but clearly not close enough.

Comment: use `dict.get(key)`

Answer (score 0):

I think you should provide the `sat` and `wed` keys before setting a value or appending the value.

```
balls = {'sat': [], 'wed': []}
```